# create xml from webform in asp.net mvc 2 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

what is the easiest way to create a structured xml file based on asp.net mvc 2  webform data ?
i am looking for a c# solution and to use maybe linq/lambda expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize your model to Xml in your controller method `ActionResult SaveMyObject(MySerializableClass myObject){ //do stuff here }`

You should be able to use one of the overloaded `XmlSerializer.Deserialize`methods found within the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace.

This is one example, found on the [MSDN Documentation site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y.aspx)

```
MySerializableClass myObject;

// Construct an instance of the XmlSerializer with the type
// of object that is being deserialized.
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));

// To read the file, create a FileStream.
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("myFileName.xml", FileMode.Open);

// Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.
myObject = (MySerializableClass) 
mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream)
```

Your object will then be deserialized into the file.  You could also use the `MemoryStream` class to deserialize it into a string variable

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you are slightly off-base here -- your object need not be serializable to use the xml serializer. They behave funamentally differently.

Comment: @Wyatt, you're right.  However, this approach should work nonetheless.

Comment: Oh the approach works, you should just fix it so you don't mention the [Serializable] bit . . .

Comment: you mean serialize it into an xml file?